# binary xml error in pagersliding tab script

Tags: android

my xml file is the following like this 
i was impotred the library from GitHub .i want 2 tabs for showing my events.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"


        >

        <com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dip"

            />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tabs" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




    </RelativeLayout>
```

my Fragmnet is this,in my java code i have set the view pager to tabs then to it,s not working please help me in this.

```
    package com.example.mindwareuae;


    import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;

    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

        FragmentManager fm;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private EventAdapter mFragmentPageAdapter;
        PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrip;
        View rootView;
        @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

             rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container);

            mFragmentPageAdapter = new EventAdapter(fm);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            viewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentPageAdapter);
            mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
        //mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(null);

            return rootView;


        }


            class EventAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            {

        public EventAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new UpComingEventFragment();
            case 1:
                return new PastEventFragment();

            default:
                return null;    
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return 2;
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "UpCommingEvent";
            case 1:
                return "PastEvent";

            default:
                break;
            }

            return super.getPageTitle(position);
        }

            }



    }
```

and my logcat showing the following error,whai binary xml error. i am not able to understand whyit's showing error.

```
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): Process: com.example.mindwareuae, PID: 1321
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at com.example.mindwareuae.EventFragment.onCreateView(EventFragment.java:27)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mindwareuae-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mindwareuae-2, /system/lib]]
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    11-27 01:02:11.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1321):     ... 20 more

pleaese help me in this
i am struct from the long time
thanks in advance
```

Comment: have you try to clean and build again ?

Comment: lot of times i was done like that

Comment: delete your `/gen` and `/bin` folders in your project and rebuild it!

Comment: thank you for giving the sugission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you imported different package name in your activity and xml. make sure that "com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip" is correctly imported in activity.

Hope this will help you friend :)

Comment: like this  11-27 01:35:45.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1435): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 01:35:45.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:85)
11-27 01:35:45.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
11-27 01:35:45.843: E/AndroidRuntime(1435):  at andalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you please help in this

Comment: import  android.app.Fragment . hoe this will work fine